# Effect of Change of Audio Bitrate on Spectrograms

Tags: audio, mp3, spectrogram, bitrate, time-frequency

I was working on changing bitrates of some MP3 files from 160kbps to 80kbps just to see how it affects the audio quality and frequencies. So I plotted the spectrogram for both waves and it looks something like this (Upper one being 80Kbps ofcourse).

[image]

I was curious to know if spectrograms are in any way related to audio bitrates but just after a simple search it turned out that they are not. It would be great if someone could explain to me the reason behind the differences in frequencies in the spectrograms if people say that there is no relation. Also if I had to analyse the differences between the two audio waves then what would be the best way to do this if people say spectrograms shouldn't be used?

Sorry if I am missing something here as I am not from the signal processing field but I am keen on learning. Any direction or links that could help me out would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably best pointing this question to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. You are correct, the way mp3 compression works is by discarding frequency domain information. The higher the compression the more data discarded.

Comment: Thanks. I'll move the question to DSP stackexachange